# BigQuery AEAD encryption/decryption fails

Tags: encryption, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I'd like to encrypt/decrypt column in BigQuery using [AEAD functions](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/aead_encryption_functions), however decryption fails with generic message:

> AEAD.DECRYPT_BYTES failed: decryption failed

Here is the sample SQL:

- create CustomerData(customer_id, keyset, favorite_animal) table
- create EncryptedCustomerData(customer_id, encrypted_animal) and encrypt data
- select and decrypt data

```
WITH CustomerData AS (
SELECT 1 AS customer_id, KEYS.NEW_KEYSET('AEAD_AES_GCM_256') AS keyset, b'jaguar' AS favorite_animal UNION ALL
SELECT 2 AS customer_id, KEYS.NEW_KEYSET('AEAD_AES_GCM_256') AS keyset, b'zebra' AS favorite_animal UNION ALL 
SELECT 3 AS customer_id, KEYS.NEW_KEYSET('AEAD_AES_GCM_256') AS keyset, b'nautilus' AS favorite_animal),
EncryptedCustomerData AS (
SELECT customer_id, AEAD.ENCRYPT(keyset, favorite_animal, CAST(CAST(customer_id AS STRING) AS BYTES)) AS encrypted_animal
FROM CustomerData AS cd)
SELECT
  ecd.customer_id,
  AEAD.DECRYPT_BYTES(
    (SELECT cd.keyset FROM CustomerData AS cd WHERE ecd.customer_id = cd.customer_id),
    ecd.encrypted_animal,
    CAST(CAST(customer_id AS STRING) AS BYTES)
  ) AS favorite_animal
FROM EncryptedCustomerData AS ecd;
```

Could you point out the error?